# How to setup form.FormController

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm creating a custom input directive. My goal is achieve that [`form.FormController`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController) behave like any other `<input>` elements with `ng-require="true"`

```
.directive('myinput', function($window, $location, $sce, $dropdown) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: '^form',
    scope: {
      model: '=myModel'
    },
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attr, formCtrl) {
         scope.$watch('model', function(newValue, oldValue) {
              if (newValue) {             
                  formCtrl.$setValidity(attr.myModel, true);  
              } else {
                  formCtrl.$setValidity(attr.myModel, false);
              }
         }, true);
    }
}
```

The above sample works fine `form[myModel].$valid` becomes true or false depending on myModel value. But that i want is `form[myModel].$error.required` becomes true.

As I can achieve this behavior?

Comment: I guess you would need to use `ng-form`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter for $setValidity method is the validator token, so what you can do is this:

```
/* 
   Point first to your input field -> formCtrl[attr.myModel] 
   and after that set the type of validator token: 'required' in your example 
*/
formCtrl[attr.myModel].$setValidity('required', true);
```

Check this example which use the build-in required directive and the custom one:

http://jsfiddle.net/oua78v19/10/